# There are no commands defined in the "ckeditor" namespace

Tags: ckeditor, symfony-4.2

I tried to install FOS\CKEditoBundle on my Symfony 4.2 project which should work with easyAdminBundle...

When I'm follow the Sensio documentation and try to execute `./bin/console ckeditor:install` command, I get this error:

`There are no commands defined in the "ckeditor" namespace`

I have update my composer.json like this:

`"auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "ckeditor:install --clear=drop": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },`

But I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I solve my issue by deleting `shivas/versioning-bundle` and repeat the instructions... On the other hand, I still do not know why ... A conflict with this versioning system (which is not essential anyway)?

Comment: Hi J1v3, it is possible to answer you own question by way of an answer instead of a comment. Marking the question solved in the title is not how it should be done: you can mark your own answer as the answer.

Comment: Hi TT, i did it :-) But i don't understand anyway where is this conflict...

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by deleting shivas/versioning-bundle and repeat the instructions... On the other hand, I still do not know why ... A conflict with this versioning system (which is not essential anyway)?